# Insert a set specified as a comma separated string into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Concept
3 Tables:

- Events (INT EventRid, Title, Desc, ....)
- Participants (INT ParticipantRid, FirstName, LastName,Address....)
- ParticipantEventMap(INT refEventRid,INT refParticipantRid)

Application (without significant re-write) will attempt to submit the data about the event (1 field per Event table field PLUS a field 'Participants' which is a comma separated list of ParticipantRids). The fields in the events table are easy to add/update but I seek a means of submitting a query which will do something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO ParticipantEventMap (refEventRid,refParticipantRid)
VALUES (10003211,(Participants));
```

Of course this is totally invalid SQL syntax, the idea being that it would expand `(10003211,(Participants))` into `(10003211,ParticipantRid[1]),(10003211,ParticipantRid[2]),...`

Is there a way do this as an SQL query, or am I required to perform all mangling on the PHP side before submitting separate queries?

Comment: I would recommend using PHP and run a loop over Participants and withing the loop insert into ParticipantEventMap.

Comment: That is what I suspect I will have to do, which is a rewrite of someone else's app...

Comment: Epiphany: 

INSERT IGNORE INTO ParticipantEventMap (SELECT 1002324 as refProgramEventRid,ParticipantRid as refParticipantRid from Participants where ParticipantRid in (1,2,3,4));  

Thus by replacing 1002324  with {EventID} and 1,2,3,4 with {Participants} in the PHP prepared statement I get the desired result! For those interested the app I'm trying to make this work in is DHTTMLx Scheduler module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ParticipantEventMap (
    SELECT 
        1002324 as refProgramEventRid,
        ParticipantRid as refParticipantRid 
    FROM Participants where ParticipantRid in (1,2,3,4));
```

Thus by replacing 1002324 with {EventID} and 1,2,3,4 with {Participants} in the PHP prepared statement I get the desired result! For those interested the app I'm trying to make this work in is DHTMLx Scheduler module.